# tensorflow/tfjs-node - Error: Expected image (BMP, JPEG, PNG, or GIF), but got unsupported image type

Tags: node.js, image, tensorflow

When trying to run [@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection) with `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` on a `nodejs` server using `express.js`, I am getting the error: `Error: Expected image (BMP, JPEG, PNG, or GIF), but got unsupported image type`.

I am sending a `base64` encoded string of an image to the server then trying to convert it to a tensor to pass into the model for prediction.

When I try to convert it to a tensor it returns the above-mentioned error. The image is of type `jpeg`. I have also tried changing the extension to `JPEG` just in case that was the issue.

I installed the packages with the following command (maybe order matters?)
`npm i --save @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection @tensorflow/tfjs-node @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu`

And am importing them as such:

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const faceLandmarksDetection = require("@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection");
```

My `base64` string: **data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIcS...** (too long to past all here)

I initially tried converting the `base64` string using node's native `Buffer.from(str, 'base64)`

```
     try {
      const model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
        faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh
      );
      const b = Buffer.from(dataObj.data_url, "base64");
      const tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(b);
      console.log("Tensor ", tensor);
      const preds = await model.estimateFaces({
        input: tensor,
      });
      console.log(preds);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

I tried converting it to an `Uint8Array` using the package [base64-arraybuffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer)

According to the tensorflow node [docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/3.9.0/#node.decodeImage) the image should be an encoded image in an Uint8Array.

```
     try {
      const model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
        faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh
      );
      const b = bBuffer.decode(dataObj.data_url);
      const tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(b); // code throwing error
      console.log("Tensor ", tensor);
      const preds = await model.estimateFaces({
        input: tensor,
      });
      console.log(preds);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

I also tried passing in the raw base64 to the `tf.node.decodeImage` method. All seem to be returning the same error!

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 4):

Managed to resolve it with trimming the base64 string before passing it into the Buffer method:

```
      const img = dataObj.data_url.replace(
        /^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/,
        ""
      );
      const b = Buffer.from(img, "base64");
      const tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(b, 3);
```